# Array as a column vs lookup table

Tags: database-design

Hi I have two tables that has one to many relationship.

```
 Table 1 Users:                     

 -------------
| id  |  name |
 -------------
| 01  |  John |
 -------------
| 02  | Harry |
 -------------

  Table 2 Cars:                     

 -------------
| id  | Brand |
 -------------
| 01  |  GM   |
 -------------
| 02  | Honda |
 -------------
```

Now any user might have multiple cars. Which one would be faster and performance efficient?

Having a array columns named carOwned in User column:

```
 Table 1 Users:                     

 ------------------------
| id  |  name | carOwned |
 ------------------------
| 01  |  John | [01, 02 ]| 
 ------------------------
| 02  | Harry | [02]     |
 ------------------------
```

Or a lookup table like?

```
   Table 3 CarOwnership:                     

 -----------------
| userId  | carId |
 -----------------
| 01      |  01   |
 -----------------
| 01      |  02   |
 -----------------
| 02      |  02   |
 -----------------
```

Comment: From a pure database design perspective, I'd go with junction table similar to your last option.

Comment: Beyond a shadow of a doubt, I agree with @SoleDBAGuy - the second option is the way to go. It obeys Codd's rules (arrays don't) and it's standard (i.e. portable) between database systems. Also, you won't have your head wrecked trying to parse arrays (in SQL - nightmare, code - barely better).

Comment: What if I am using a nosql database?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use the Lookup Table approach. If absolutely necessary there are tools in most database implementations you can use to turn rows into an array like result for another application to use. But as far as Databases are concerned stick to the row method to maintain a nice clean relational model you can JOIN easily on.

Comment: Won't it save a SQL query with the array column approach?

Comment: By save do you mean use less queries? That's entirely dependent on how your writing your queries and for what purpose, but there is no reason a single well built query could not return results in any desired format from either example. However, SQL is not designed to handle array lists of data, trying to manipulate or JOIN on that sort of data circumvents the Relational model that most SQL implementations are based around. If there is no reason for that data to ever exist as anything besides a List, then sure it's a better. But if your actually relating data across multiple tables, then no.

Comment: This method also preserves data integrity by being able to force a foreign key relationship. You will not be able to do that with the array method which could result in orphan data.